# In Klingon culture, is there a specific meaning behind crossing your arms and/or turning away (besides discommendation)?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, klingon

Is this gesture only reserved for the discommendation ceremony (*TNG*: “Sins of the Father”), and subsequent reminders of the status (*TNG*: “Reunion”)?

Have we seen Klingons use that gesture under any other circumstances?

Comment: There are multiple questions here. You need to remove the ones that are too broad (*Has that gesture been used anywhere else? What about similar gestures in other sci-fi worlds?*)

Comment: FYI - I removed the part of the question asking if similar gestures are used in other SF works, as that's overly broad on the face of it. Without that, I believe this is an answerable question. If you disagree with the edit, feel free to roll it back, of course. And, welcome to SFF.SE!

Answer (score 3):

In the canon thus far at this writing, the gesture has only been used in relation to discommendation. Given how seriously being discommended is taken in Klingon culture, it seems unlikely that the gesture would be used casually or in a way that would be confused with its discommendation-related meaning.

See: ["Discommendation" on Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Discommendation)

Comment: Could you edit in some evidence to back this up?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that's going to be difficult. Unless there is a word from god saying this explicitly you can't really prove this negative statement. You can only prove it wrong.

Comment: @Jontia Evidence can at least be added to prove the gesture has been used for this purpose though.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot that evidence is in the question. All TV uses of the gesture according to [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Discommendation) are already listed in the question itself. Oops, except House of Quark.

Comment: @Jontia Still, I think you understand what I mean. This is just very unsubstantial.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot "No" answers often are. But you're right. The House of Quark reference and maybe the Memory-alpha and beta links would be useful.

Comment: I agree that a negative statement is not terribly satisfying, but other than linking to Discommendation in Memory Alpha, I'm not sure how to make it more satisfying. Memory Alpha doesn't have an article specifically for the arms-crossed-across-the-chest gesture, probably because it's already adequately covered in the Discommendation article and isn't used in other contexts.